# insert multiple images to database using single submit button through php

Tags: php, mysql

Here, i am trying to insert multiple images to database, but it is not happening with this code, i am inserting only the name of the image to database and move the images to a specific path. For a single image upload, its working, when i try to upload multiple images then it goes wrong. Please suggest me your ideas. Advance thanx to all. I am newbie in php, just trying to learn.

```
 $img_name = $_FILES['banner']['name'];
 $img_size = $_FILES['banner']['size'];
 $img_temp = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
 $pht_name = $_FILES['photos']['name'];
 $pht_size = $_FILES['photos']['size'];
 $pht_temp = $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'];
 $pht_name_a = $_FILES['photos_a']['name'];
 $pht_size_a = $_FILES['photos_a']['size'];
 $pht_temp_a = $_FILES['photos_a']['tmp_name'];
 $pht_name_b = $_FILES['photos_b']['name'];
 $pht_size_b = $_FILES['photos_b']['size'];
 $pht_temp_b = $_FILES['photos_b']['tmp_name'];

include "_lib/_req/conn.php";
// section 1 (page contents)
$name = $pg_name . '_540x165_' . '.' . $img_ext;
$path = "_img\\gallery\\540x165\\";
$target_path = $path . $name;
if(move_uploaded_file($img_temp, $target_path)){
$insert = "INSERT INTO page_content (p_c_id, p_c_name, p_c_link, p_c_group, p_c_text, p_c_img, p_c_tag) 
VALUES ('', '$pg_name', '$pg_link', '$pg_group', '$text', '$name', '$pg_tag')";
$query = mysql_query($insert);              
}
else{ die(mysql_error()); }
$md5_6 = substr(md5(rand()),0,6);
$name_a = $pg_name . '_258x130_' . $md5_6 . '.' . $pht_ext;
$path_a = "_img\\gallery\\258x130\\";
$target_path_a = $path_a . $name_a;
if(move_uploaded_file($pht_temp, $target_path_a)){
    $insert_a = "INSERT INTO page_photos (p_p_id, p_p_name, p_p_img) 
    VALUES ('', '$pg_name', '$name_a')";
    $query_a = mysql_query($insert_a);
}
else{ die(mysql_error()); }
// page photo no.2
$md5_7 = substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
$name_b = $pg_name . '_258x130_' . $md5_7 . '.' . $pht_ext_a;
$path_b = "_img\\gallery\\258x130\\";
$target_path_b = $path_b . $name_b;
if(move_uploaded_file($pht_temp_a, $target_path_b)){
    $insert_b = "INSERT INTO page_photos (p_p_id, p_p_name, p_p_img) 
    VALUES ('', '$pg_name', '$name_b')";
    $query_b = mysql_query($insert_b);
}
else{ die(mysql_error()); }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You'll need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it may helps you,

Please use the below query respective section in your code, Assumed 'p_p_id' is primary key so i have removed from the queries.

```
     //page_content
     $insert = "INSERT INTO page_content (p_c_name, p_c_link, p_c_group, p_c_text, p_c_img, p_c_tag) VALUES ('$pg_name', '$pg_link', '$pg_group', '$text', '$name', '$pg_tag')";

     //page_photos
     $insert_a = "INSERT INTO page_photos (p_p_name, p_p_img) VALUES ('$pg_name', '$name_a')";

     //page_photos
     $insert_b = "INSERT INTO page_photos (p_p_name, p_p_img)  VALUES ('$pg_name', '$name_b')";
```

Can you please check the upload path and its permission and also

```
   $path = "_img\\gallery\\540x165\\";   

Change it as 

   $path = "_img/gallery/540x165/";   //in all
```

For the multiple file upload,

input file tag should be,

```
   <input type='file' name='file[]' multiple>
```

then sample PHP code for multiple file upload as in below,

```
         $count=0;             
         foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) 
        {
            $target='';//folder path
            $tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count];
            $count=$count + 1;
            $target=$target.'/'.basename($filename);
            move_uploaded_file($tmp,$target);
              // your insert query here              

        }
```

For more help, http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: sorry to say, its not worked.

Comment: Can you please check the upload folder path permission?

Comment: try the new one, changing slashes but not worked. trying to upload single file is ok but multiple is not working.

Comment: what you meant by the multiple file upload ?

Comment: mean that there is five file upload button to select files and a single submit button to upload all the files to specific directory.

Comment: You mean 5 banner and 5 photos browse button like that ?

Comment: no i mean 1 banner and 4 photos browse button.

Comment: uploading file to the specific directory is done, but the name of the image is not in the database, inserting a 0 in the position of image name everytime a image is uploaded.